# Setting up Laravel Fortify's password confirmation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

Laravel Fortify creates a new route, `/user/confirm-password` that takes a password input. This route hits the `store` method of `Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ConfirmablePasswordController`.

The return in this controller method is as follows:

```
return $confirmed
            ? app(PasswordConfirmedResponse::class)
            : app(FailedPasswordConfirmationResponse::class);
```

What I'm not understanding is that both of these classes are empty interfaces. I need it to return JSON in the event the route was hit with an XHR request, so something like this from another Fortify controller method:

```
return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse('', 200)
            : back()->with('status', 'two-factor-authentication-enabled');
```

How do I get the JSON response I want from the `/user/confirm-password` route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I was missing. Unsure on how exactly I overlooked it but the [Customising Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects) section of the Fortify docs covers how to solve this for other contracts.

Adding the following to my `FortifyServiceProvider`'s `register` method was the solution.

```
$this->app->instance(PasswordConfirmedResponse::class, new class implements PasswordConfirmedResponse {
    public function toResponse($request) {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse(['confirmed' => true], 200)
            : back()->with('confirmed', true);
    }
});

$this->app->instance(FailedPasswordConfirmationResponse::class, new class implements FailedPasswordConfirmationResponse {
    public function toResponse($request) {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse(['confirmed' => false], 200)
            : back()->with('confirmed', false);
    }
});
```